# How to sort dates in a list?

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a list of Objects . The list is already sorted in order by date of the booking. I would like to create a new list which takes todays date as an argument and stores the last 10 booking and next 10 bookings as of todays date.

How can this be done?

```
transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        String hql = "FROM Booking ORDER BY scheduledDate";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List<Booking> bookingList = query.list();
Date now = new Date();
        List<Booking> lessThan = null;
        List<Booking> moreThan = null;

        for(int i =0; i<bookingList.size();i++){

            if(bookingList.get(i).getScheduledDate().compareTo(now)<0)
                lessThan.add(bookingList.get(i));

            if (bookingList.get(i).getScheduledDate().compareTo(now)>0)
                moreThan.add(bookingList.get(i));
        }
```

These are my getter methods.

```
public java.util.Date getScheduledDate() {
    return scheduledDate;
}
```

Comment: Please provide your getter method and if you are using your own compareTo please also provide that.

Comment: lessThan and moreThan are null referenced... what issue are yu getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a new list by taking the absolute values of the result of the difference of today's date and each of the dates in the date-list you have.

Find the position of the minimum number in the new list. You can then get the positions of the dates you require from here. min-pos to (min-pos + 9) will give you 10 records of next 10 bookings and (min-pos - 1) to (min-pos - 10) will give you the other set.

The result will differ a little based on whether the (today's date - date-at-min-pos)  is greater than or less than zero. Then (min-pos+1) to (min-pos + 10) will give you 10 records of next 10 bookings and (min-pos) to (min-pos - 9) will give you the other set

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with Java 8's `stream`, e.g.:

```
List<Booking> bookingList = query.list();
final Date today = new Date();
List<Booking> greaterThan = bookingList.stream()
        .filter(b -> b.getScheduledDate().after(today))
        .limit(10)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Booking> lessThan = bookingList.stream()
        .filter(b -> b.getScheduledDate().before(today))
        .limit(10)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: How can I add to another List<Booking> for example

Comment: `booking.addAll(greaterThan);` However, lists produced by the above code will be `another` lists only.